# Ошибка Another git process seems to be running in this repository

Tags: git

`git add` выдает такое:

> Another git process seems to be running in this repository, e.g.
>   an editor opened by 'git commit'.

Что делать?

Comment: Закрыть этот самый "another git process"?

Answer (score 13):

Такое бывает, если прервать операцию с репозиторием "внезапно". Или какая то программа решила без Вашего ведома работать с репой.

Если Вы не уверены, что какая то программа может работать с репой без Вашего ведома - перегрузите комп.

В противном случае в репе найдите в папке .git файл index.lock и удалите его

```
rm .git/index.lock
```

Comment: Спасибо!!! Удалил .lock и все пошло отлично!!!

Comment: Спасибо и от меня. Только учусь, а тут беда с git. Все сделала в точности как посоветовали. Спасибо вам, что делитесь такими советами!

Answer (score 6):

Гит когда выполняет какую то команду блокирует себя же, чтобы паралельно ничего не делали с файлами.

Если вы уверены что у вас нет паралельно ничего запущено тогда просто с папки `.git` удалите `.lock` файлы, если память не изменяет там должен быть `index.lock` файл.

Comment: Спасибо!!! Удалил .lock и все пошло отлично!!!